# Cannot terminate cstring properly

Tags: c++, c-strings

I'm making a program that finds the most frequently inputted character and outputs it but a junk character takes over the output if it's less than the array value. I've tried putting null in multiple places. Putting it at the end, putting it at the beginning. It keeps giving me the junk character ╠ for some reason.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void getMaxCharfrequ(char arr[], int size) {
    arr[0] = '\0';
    char maxChar = ' ';
    int maxfreq = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int count = 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                count++;
        if (count > maxfreq)
            maxfreq = count;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int count = 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                count++;
        if (count == maxfreq)
            maxChar = arr[i];
    }

    cout << "The max character frequency is " << maxChar << " with frequency " << maxfreq;
    
}
#define size 15
void main() {
    char arr[size];
    arr[0] = '\0';
    cout << "Please enter your string: ";
    cin >> arr;
    getMaxCharfrequ(arr, size);
}
```

Comment: What is the input you're using? What is the output? What do you expect the output to be? Since you never actually print a string I'm not sure why you think lack of termination is the problem.

Comment: Don't pass the `size` to `getMaxCharFrequ()` function. Instead, pass the _size_ of input string to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple problems with your code. Before discussing the problems, a suggestion - Read about `std::string` in `C++` and going forward start using it instead of plain `C` style character array. I am leaving it up to you to use `std::string` in your program. Below answer is pointing out the problem in your existing code. Lets discuss them one by one:

**First**:

In `main()` function, you are doing

```
arr[0] = '\0';
```

before taking input from user. Its not required because `cin` adds a null terminator at the end when reading `char *`.

**Second**:

You are reading user input like this -

```
cin >> arr;
```

What happen when user input more than `15` characters?

At least use `cin.get (arr, size)`. Best would be to use `std::string`, instead of plain `char` array.

**Third**:

You are passing `size` to `getMaxCharfrequ()` function. `size` is macro which will expand to value `15`. In the `getMaxCharfrequ()` function, you are iterating loop till `size`, so whatever the input user will give, the loop will iterate `15` times which is not correct. This is also the root cause of the problem that you are facing. Instead, the loop should iterate for the number of characters in input string, e.g., if user give input string `hello`, the loop should iterate for `5` characters only. You should pass the length of input string, instead of `size`, to `getMaxCharfrequ()` function or you can also iterate till `\0` character of string and, in this case, you don't need to pass the length of string.

**Fourth**:

In the `getMaxCharfrequ()` function, the first statement is

```
arr[0] = '\0';
```

That means, you are overwriting the first character of user input with null terminating character. You don't need to do this.

**Fifth**:

You don't need to reiterate the string again to identify the maximum frequency character. Rather, you can do it while calculating the frequency of characters in the string. Just record the character when `count > maxfreq`.

**Sixth**:

The return type of `main()` should be `int`.

**Seventh**:

This

```
using namespace std;
```

is [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), avoid it.

Putting these altogether, you can do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void getMaxCharfrequ(char arr[], size_t size) {
    char maxChar = ' ';
    int maxfreq = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int count = 1;
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > maxfreq) {
            maxfreq = count;
            maxChar = arr[i];
        }
    }

    if (arr[0] == '\0') {
        std::cout << "Input string is empty" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "The max character frequency is " << maxChar << " with frequency " << maxfreq << std::endl;
    }
    
}

#define size 15

int main() {
    char arr[size];

    std::cout << "Please enter your string: ";
    std::cin.get(arr, size);
    getMaxCharfrequ(arr, strlen(arr));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
Please enter your string: helloworld
The max character frequency is l with frequency 3
# ./a.out
Please enter your string: 
Input string is empty
# ./a.out
Please enter your string: aaabbbbcc
The max character frequency is b with frequency 4
# ./a.out
Please enter your string: aaabbggggg
The max character frequency is g with frequency 5
```

Comment: Thank you. Normally I would be using std::string but for this project the challenge was to use c-string only.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is given and accepted. I would like to additionally present a more modern C++ solution that will work with any iterable container.

Please the the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <list>

// Some Alias names for later easier reading --------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Container>
using ValueType = std::ranges::range_value_t<Container>;

template <typename Container>
using Pair = std::pair<ValueType<Container>, size_t>;

template <typename Container>
using Counter = std::unordered_map<ValueType<Container>, size_t>;

template <typename Container>
using UnderlyingContainer = std::vector<Pair<Container>>;

// Predicate Functor
template <class Container> struct LessForSecondOfPair {
    bool operator ()(const Pair<Container>& p1, const Pair<Container>& p2) { return p1.second < p2.second; }
};

template <typename Container>
using MaxHeap = std::priority_queue<Pair<Container>, UnderlyingContainer<Container>, LessForSecondOfPair<Container>>;

// Calculate max element ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Container>
auto topFrequent(const Container& data) {

    if constexpr (std::ranges::range<Container>) {  // Evaluated at compile time

        // Count all occurences of data
        Counter<Container> counter{};
        for (const auto& d : data) counter[d]++;

        // Build a Max-Heap
        MaxHeap<Container> maxHeap(counter.begin(), counter.end());

        // Return most frequent element
        return maxHeap.top().first;
    }
    else
        return data;
}

// Test
int main() {
    std::vector testVector{ 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7 };
    std::cout << "Most frequent is: " << topFrequent(testVector) << "\n";

    std::list testList{ 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7 };
    std::cout << "Most frequent is: " << topFrequent(testList) << "\n";

    double cStyleArray[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 2.2, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3 };
    std::cout << "Most frequent is: " << topFrequent(cStyleArray) << "\n";

    std::string s{ "abbcccddddeeeeeffffffggggggg" };
    std::cout << "Most frequent is: " << topFrequent(s) << "\n";

    double value = 12.34;
    std::cout << "Most frequent is: " << topFrequent(value) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Basically it does not matter, if you use an array or a `std::string`. The algorithm will work with any kind of iterable container.

Answer (score 0):

Good answers are already given, but here's a much simpler to do that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main(void) {
  std::map<char, int> map;
  std::string input = "aaabbcddaaaddkladfaa";
  int max_freq = 0;
  char max_char;

  for (auto ch : input) {
    map[ch]++;
    if (map[ch] > max_freq) {
      max_freq = map[ch];
      max_char = ch;
    }
  }

  std::cout << "Character '" << max_char
            << "' is most frequent, which is appeared " << max_freq << " times";

  return 0;
}
```